# flask limiter for millisecond in text suggestion API as user types

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have one Api which gives suggestion to user as he types.
i want to restrict the Api call to 2 per millisecond
i have used flask limiter package but not able to get millisecond limiter for my Api.
currently it provides 5 Api call per millisecond.

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippet.

Comment: Documentation of Flask-Limiter clearly says its not supporting milliseconds https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#rate-limit-string-notation